# Type of method in Java

Tags: java, methods, types, switch-statement

Im new in Java and im trying this ex but it's giving me some problems with method's type of "primoGiorno":
I think it should be right ( "primoGiorno" takes int and return int) but it gives me error: 
"This method must return a result of type int"; I cant understand why:
it returns, by switching "x": 0, 1, 2, etc.. that are int values. Where am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CheGiorno {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Selezionare numero da 0 (Lunedì) a 6 (Domenica");
        int inizioAnno =  scanner.nextInt();
        primoGiorno (inizioAnno);




        scanner.close();

    }


    private static int primoGiorno (int x) {
        switch (x) {
        case 0 : return 0; break;
        case 1 : return 1; break;
        case 2 : return 2; break;
        case 3 : return 3; break;
        case 4 : return 4; break;
        case 5 : return 5; break;
        case 6 : return 6; break;
        default : System.out.println ("Valore errato");             
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Look at what happens if you reach the `default`. Also you don't need a `break` after a `return`

Comment: You program expects `primoGiorno` to return an int. You need to return an int, say -1, when you reach the default. Also, you can remove your `break;` statements because they will never be reached since you return anyways.

Comment: If `x > 6` or `x < 0` which of the return statements are you going to hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line breaks it:

`default : System.out.println ("Valore errato");`

If it reaches the default value, it still must return an int value, which `System.out.println ("Valore errato");` is clearly not.

A customary thing to have functions which return int do in the case of error is return -1.

Something like this:

```
    private static int primoGiorno (int x) {
        switch (x) {
        case 0 : return 0; break;
        case 1 : return 1; break;
        case 2 : return 2; break;
        case 3 : return 3; break;
        case 4 : return 4; break;
        case 5 : return 5; break;
        case 6 : return 6; break;
        default : return -1;             
       }

    }
```

You can also remove the `break;` statements because `return` ends the function anyway.

Comment: *"You can also remove the `break`"* — Well, you *must* remove the breaks, because they are unreachable, hence the compiler reports a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

In method "primoGiorno", the default case of switch statement if met, it returns nothing, but prints. Provide a return statement for default case with an int value.

Remove the break statements after return, it is unreachable code.